# Is multiplicity of pull-back preserved under injective morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If you have injective morphism $F : X \rightarrow Y$ between two projective varieties, is it true if $F$ is injective then the multiplicities of cycles are preserved? If $n_1V_1 \sim n_2V_2 \subset Y \implies n_1F^{\ast}(V_1) \sim n_2F^{\ast}(V_2) \subset X.$?

Comment: You are actually asking if rational equivalence is preserved, right? Also, how do you define the pull-back of a cycle along an arbitrary morphism? I'm not 100% sure this is a well-defined notion. E.g. Fulton only defines the pull-back of cycles for flat morphisms in *Intersection Theory*. In that case, pull-back preserves rational equivalence. So if your $X$ is an open subset of $Y$, it works.

Comment: @red_trumpet I forgot to add that that $F$ is flat injective morphism. Is it true that the multiplicities are preserved?

Comment: Then yes, see Fulton's  book for a reference. Also I'm pretty sure that flat injective morphisms of varieties are open embeddings, so $X$ is an open of $Y$. Are you sure both are projective varieties? Then you would get $X = Y$...